# Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch, unless I use sudo

Tags: node.js, watch, ulimit

### Description

Recently I've run into an problem. I am not able to run `yarn start` in `element-web` directory, I get these [errors](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/93v6Yx58DT/). Originally I thought it had something to do with `element-web` itself so I created an [issue](https://github.com/vector-im/element-web/issues/15750). Some time after that I tried to run `wintersmith preview` in [`bibviz`](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/bibviz) directory and got the same errors. This was weird so I tried to create an Angular project and run `ng serve` and errors again. I headed to the issue to close it as it wasn't an `element-web` issue. I found that there was another [issue](https://github.com/vector-im/element-web/issues/15774) created with the same problem. It had already been closed by [`turt2live`](https://github.com/turt2live) saying `it looks like you've run out of memory on your system`. Based on this I tried to turn of most programs running in the background and now all the commands worked.

I am sure that `ng serve` used to work in the past.

My PC has 16 GB of RAM and the commands already fail when I am on 7/16 GB. I can't see any memory spikes when running the commands. Running the commands with `sudo` also completely eliminates the problem. This doesn't make any sense to me.

Research lead me to `ulimits` but they seem to have no effect. I have also installed `watchman` with no effect.

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Thank you in advance!

### Info

I am on Debian 11 Bullseye. This is the output of a few commands that could be useful.

As a regular user:

```sh
> uname -a
Linux Simon-s-PC 5.8.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.8.14-1 (2020-10-10) x86_64 GNU/Linux
> sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288
> ulimit -a
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8192
-c: core file size (blocks)         0
-m: resident set size (kbytes)      unlimited
-u: processes                       46482
-n: file descriptors                8192
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  unlimited
-v: address space (kbytes)          unlimited
-x: file locks                      unlimited
-i: pending signals                 63664
-q: bytes in POSIX msg queues       819200
-e: max nice                        0
-r: max rt priority                 95
-N 15:                              unlimited
> yarn --version
1.22.5
```

With `sudo su`:

```sh
> sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288
> ulimit -a
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8192
-c: core file size (blocks)         0
-m: resident set size (kbytes)      unlimited
-u: processes                       63664
-n: file descriptors                1024
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  2043392
-v: address space (kbytes)          unlimited
-x: file locks                      unlimited
-i: pending signals                 63664
-q: bytes in POSIX msg queues       819200
-e: max nice                        0
-r: max rt priority                 0
-N 15:                              unlimited
```

Comment: The same problem with new vue.js project on debian 12. Solution in answer help well.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think I've found a solution:

- Set limits in `/etc/sysctl.conf` by adding:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
fs.inotify.max_user_instances=512
```

- Open a new terminal or reload `sysctl.conf` variables with

  ```
  sudo sysctl --system
  ```
- Run `yarn start`

Everything should work fine now, hopefully. If it doesn't work try setting the limits higher.